# Cracked toilet seat hinge: repair seat or replace seat?

Tags: toilet

Does it ever make sense to repair or replace a broken toilet seat hinge? The seat is in good condition otherwise, but a new seat is under $50.

Just a standard elongated toilet seat from glacier bay with plastic hinges.

Comment: It's hard to give a great answer without seeing the seat and hinges, can you post some pictures? It would be good to see the broken hinge.

Comment: Pretty much depends on whether you can find reasonable replacement hinges, which is often difficult. Repairing broken plastic hinges is a form of tilting at windmills I'd suggest you skip, but feel free to experience the frustration yourself if you like.

Comment: I think this is opinion based. My little brother will not deal with toilet problems even though he built his home including the plumbing. I might repair, he would replace.

Comment: I would say it _always_ makes sense to repair or replace a broken toilet seat hinge. Whether you do it by fixing up just the hinge or replacing the whole assembly is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

I see universal hinge replacements online for $10, but a new seat (low-end) would cost $10-$20.

This is somewhat of a personal decision. My recommendation would be to start by trying to glue the hinge back together if that makes sense. Use a glue that says it works on plastic. Will this work? Maybe, but you probably have an appropriate glue lying around the house somewhere, so there's little actual risk. I think it's likely that it'll break again after a while, but that might give you a few more months of use for free.

If that doesn't work, I'd just buy a cheap replacement. I did a quick look over Lowes, and they don't seem to offer seats with nylon hinges, and while they have "chromed" options, that phrasing sounds dubious, and the design doesn't look strong; I doubt it offers much more in the way of durability over plastic. What it looks like is that paying more money can get you more style (a wooden seat, or a padded seat, or different colors), but not more durability. On the other hand, my experience has been that the cheap seats are actually okay, and won't snap in half after a month or disintegrate when humid. My usual recommendation is to buy the cheapest option that is actually designed to last, and even the cheap seats seem to pass that test.

Comment: Where agree with trying to repair, first need to find what type of plastic then find best repair for it.  Most need specific glue for type of plastic, some do good with plastic welding(might get by with using soldiering tool/gun), repaired a long brush handle like this.

Comment: While gluing plastic works better if you know the type of plastic, the idea is to attempt the repair with whatever they already have, since a reasonable replacement is so cheap. It's a bit of a roll of the dice, but it's a free roll, so worth trying.

Comment: Plastics are funny, one right glue will make a permanent repair, another will do nothing or can damage it for right repair.  Google can usually find type and proper repair.  Might be mistaken about power of google.

Answer (score 1):

I am all for repairing it- I really hate the way everything is made to be disposable these days. Let's put less in the landfill and save some money- I say look into doing the repair.

Now, I have never seen replacement toilet seat hinges for sale- that *could* be a problem. It seems like a brief investigation would let you know if you have a chance of finding it or not. I would first check the box stores, then the plumbing supply houses, and then see if you can get through to the manufacturer.

I say - YES ! try and repair it- worst case you have to buy a new seat.

Comment: Replacement hinges are easy to find at home improvement, plumbing supply stores. Indeed, building material salvage yards might even have them for a buck or two. I vote for repair...unless the seat is uncomfortable.