# Hi, This Part of my Toilet Seat Broke. What is the Recommended Fix?

Tags: toilet

[image: Picture of toilet]

It’s a Mayfair toilet seat. I still have the part that broke off.

Comment: Get a new one..

Comment: A plastic type glue should work, but most seats are inexpensive and might just replace with a new one.

Comment: There should be a pin? where is it ?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/217667/25178

Comment: I suspect that the plastic used in those things is not very adhesive-friendly.  Just replace it!

Answer (score 9):

You might try something along the lines of epoxy, but, unfortunately, in all likelihood the best "fix" will be to install a new toilet seat.

Comment: Obviously the right answer.

Comment: ...and choose a different brand, in hopes of finding a shred more build quality (good luck with that part.)

Comment: The wood ones seem to hold up better.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try glueing.

You might accidentally glue it so that the will not move any more. Also the glue surface is very small to hold anything.

Replacement is the best choice

Comment: Also, the inevitable 'lines' the glue creates between the broken pieces will have discoloration and attract dirt, leading the wife to complain. Replacement is the only answer that solves all short and long term issues, given the overall cost.